# Styling cells with macro

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

I'm new with OO Calc macros. With this code I can style cells on `F13:F16` range

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****
Option Explicit

Sub Main
oDoc = ThisComponent
osheets = odoc.getSheets()
osheet = osheets.getByIndex(0)
oCells = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("F13:F16")
NewBorder = oCells.BottomBorder
NewBorder.OuterLineWidth = 3
oCells.BottomBorder = NewBorder
End Sub
```

How can I edit this code so I can style cells I currently selected with mouse, instead of specifying them in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Working with selected cells is a bit complex because either a single cell, a cell range, or multiple cell ranges may be selected.

Code that handles all of these possibilities is explained in the essential [Andrew's Macro Document](https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) under section *6.5.1. Simple example processing selected cells*.

Comment: Jim is referring to the link at the very top of the URL he sent. Andrew Pitonyak also has a complete book link further down below called "**OpenOffice.org Macros Explained.odt V4**".  In that book, the reference chapter is _15.8.1. Selected cells_.